# abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")

Tags: configuration, mercurial

I have added repository and at the time of commit I get error as

```
error:  abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")
```

I am not getting Mercurial.ini file on my local as well. Does anyone know how I can resolve this error on Fedora?

Comment: The Mercurial.ini file is the user config file on Windows. On Fedora it would probably be ~/.hgrc

Answer (score 181):

Either put a hgrc in the .hg directory in your repo or put a .hgrc (hgrc for Windows) file in your home dir (then it covers all your projects)
In the file you should write

```
[ui]
username = Your Name <your@mail>
```

Comment: in unix or cygwin the file in your homedir starts with a dot: .hgrc

Comment: Yeah, gregm edited it to windows filenames so I clarified it now, covering both.

Comment: From [Mercurial 3.0](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads) may be helpful the `hg config -e` command which opens editor with your home configuration file. See `hg help -c config` for more options.

Comment: Silly me! Kept forgettin the [ui] tag!

Answer (score 55):

On Windows, these configuration files are read:

```
- "<repo>\.hg\hgrc"
- "%USERPROFILE%\.hgrc"
- "%USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini"
- "%HOME%\.hgrc"
- "%HOME%\Mercurial.ini"
- "C:\Mercurial\Mercurial.ini"
- "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial"
- "<install-dir>\Mercurial.ini"
```

On Unix, these files are read:

```
- "<repo>/.hg/hgrc"
- "$HOME/.hgrc"
- "/etc/mercurial/hgrc"
- "/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc"
- "<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc"
- "<install-root>/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc"
```

Include the following in one of these files above:

```
[ui]
username = Your Name <your@mail>
```

Comment: it does,     [ui] username = Your Name tells how to specify username.

Comment: It really doesn't because it doesn't say which file is supposed to store the username nor does it explain why it doesn't have or hasn't asked to register a username in the first place.

Comment: Being pedantic, the above comments are right, this does not answer the question. Nevertheless, it adds useful information, so +1.

Answer (score 19):

Simple answer - in your .hg folder, create a file named .hgrc 
in there, add the following content (check `hg help config` for the exact syntax)

```
[ui]
username = forename surname <forename.surnamce@email.com>
verbose = True
```

and save it.  Should work now.  Note that verbose = True is not required, but I included it since it is listed in the help content

(This is from memory, but `hg help config` will tell you the correct filename and syntax)

Comment: as I said in the answer, it isn't required, but I put it in since that's what `hg help config` outputs.  Just in the answer for consistency. :)

Comment: It's better to put username in your user-global ~/.hgrc file, not in a per-repo file.

Comment: if you place the file in projectdir/.hg, then it should be projectdir/.hg/hgrc, not .hgrc

Comment: Followed your directions Ry4an and did:
touch ~/.hgrc
edit ~/.hgrc

then past the contents of zombie sheep's anser, mine the verbose bit, into the file. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 16):

run **hg config --edit**  ( tested it in *hg 3.1* both on *linux debian* and *windows*)
it will create (if not exists) and open a file with text:

```
# example config (see "hg help config" for more info)

[ui]
# name and email, e.g.
# username = Jane Doe <jdoe@example.com>
username = 

[extensions]
# uncomment these lines to enable some popular extensions
# (see "hg help extensions" for more info)
# pager =
# progress =
# color =
```

fill "username" field and save the file

Comment: @lazycommit, which is your hg version and OS? I checked in 3.1.1 in linux debian and windows 7 - it works there. Maybe your hg is older.

Comment: 2.8.2 yes, it is old)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the current user owns the hgrc file or otherwise has correct permissions for it.

Answer (score 1):

put file .hgrc in $HOME or home/user