# Mercurial on Mac. hg commitabort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")

Tags: macos, mercurial

I have installed Mercurial and BitBucket on my Mac. I created a repository and was able to add files. But I get no username supplied when trying to commit. The solution involved editing the .hgrc file. But this does not exist on my machine. Do I need to create it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial: abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477781/mercurial-abort-no-username-supplied-see-hg-help-config)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need to create `~/.hgrc`.  For example, a minimal version that only includes the necessary username:

```
[ui]
username = John Doe <jdoe@acme.com>
```

The value of the username property is free-form text, but the convention is as shown (`Full Name <emailaddress>`).

As an alternative, you could create/edit `.hg/hgrc` inside your repository.  In that case, the `username` you set would apply only to that repository.  `~/.hgrc` is for per-user configuration, while `.hg/hgrc` inside a repository is for configuration that should apply only to that repository.  If a given property exists in both, the value in the repository-specific `hgrc` overrides the value in the global `~/.hgrc`.  The syntax is the same regardless. `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` is for the system-global configuration, but usually not a good place to define the `username`.

Use `man hgrc` for more information.